# Why flex property doesn't work on flex-items when setting it on the container?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

The problem is that when I set flex on the container which is section, nothing happens but when I set it individually on flex-items, it works properly. Doesn't flex property get inherited by the items or I'm missing something?

Also, another problem is that when I set flex-shrink on main and aside with different values(like 3 for main and 2 for aside) it doesn't seem to work.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 5px;
}

header {
  display: block;
  background-color: red;
}

aside {
  background-color: green;
}

main {
  background: purple;
}

footer {
  background-color: black;
  display: block;
}


/* main, aside {
      flex-grow: inherit;
    } */

section {
  display: flex;
  height: 50em;
  flex: 1 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <h1>Header</h1>
  </header>
  <section>
    <aside>aside</aside>
    <main>main</main>
  </section>
  <footer>
    footer
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flex is a shorthand for flex-grow, flex-shrink and flex-basis. It applies to flex children and has nothing to do with container. 
As for a second question, flex-shrink defines a rate at which different flex children shrink if you reduce the screen size, not sure what is not working there, should work normally.

Comment: What about the second question?

Comment: @Boypro added it to the answer

Comment: So I guess that there are no a specific explanation to shrink problem? Well I guess that's fine. The items shrink themselves anyway. Thank you!

Comment: @Boypro if one of children has flex-shrink of 1 and another of 2 the one with 2 will shrink twice as fast. If you have more questions iam here to help)

Comment: That's the problem. I set the items to different values, main to 1 and aside to 2 and they still shrink the same. Also, I have another question, why the header shrinks itself without being a flex-item of a container? Thank you for the help though.

Comment: @Boypro Please show me the problematic behavior of header with image so i can help you with that

Comment: A header's width is not by percentage so it shouldn't shrink by itself when you shrink the windows, isn't?

Comment: @Boypro In your example it has no width at all, which means that by default it would take up only the space needed for its content. Also all plain html tags are responsive by default and would shrink.

Comment: But if that is the case, then why we would need to make @Media query to make stuff responsive?

Comment: @Boypro For many reasons such as changing the way things are positioned on different devices, hiding or showing smth on different screen sizes, changing font sizes, margins, paddings. In short, to make your website look good on availible devices and in all browsers that you want to support. Some things just scale well by themselves, some dont, and thats why we need mediaqueries.

Comment: Oh ok then. That makes so much sense. Sorry for all these questions, I find CSS very hard recently. Thank you for the help!!

Comment: @Boypro I'm glad I helped)